# Continue code if user input isn't given C

Tags: c, input, semaphore, sleep

My question is the following:

Is there a way to continue my code and skip the input if a certain time is passed

for example :

```
printf("How old are you");

int age;
scanf("%d",&age);
// I don't know how to check if the time has been exeeded
sleep(5)

if("Time exeeded"){
 printf("It's seems like the user is not there\n\n Goodbye");
 return 1;

}
else {
 printf("You are %d",age);
 return 0;
}
```

Thank you for your answers

Comment: You'll need to run two different threads here (that's the context in which `semaphore`s are used).

Comment: I have to focus my research on sem_wait and sem_post?

Comment: You can't solve this with standard C. You'll need an input function which isn't blocking. And it's gonna be OS-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical solution is to use a timeout on `select`:

```
/* Set a 10 second timer on a scanf */

#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(void)
{
    struct timeval tp = { .tv_sec = 10, .tv_usec = 0 };
    char b[32];
    fd_set fds;

    FD_ZERO(&fds);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds);
    switch( select(STDIN_FILENO + 1, &fds, NULL, NULL, &tp) ){
    case 1:
        if( FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &fds) ){
            if( scanf("%31s", b) == 1 ){
                printf("Read: %s\n", b);
            }
        }
        break;
    case 0:
        puts("Timeout");
        break;
    default:
        fputs("Error\n", stderr);
    }
}
```

Comment: note: if the user messes with their terminal settings, they may be able to send some characters, but not the whole string. So scanf may still wait for the rest of the string, without timeout.